# Access Exchange (2016) audit logs with EWS Managed API

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, audit, exchange-server-2016

I wrote a tiny EWS API program in C# to check Exchange audit logs. The test is against an Exchange 2016 server.

When I'm trying to check the admin audit logs folder:

```
Folder myFolder= Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.AdminAuditLogs);
```

I get an "access is denied" error:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
```

Since it's a test environment, I've granted the user I'm using all sort of  permissions (domain/enterprise admin in the domain, Organization Management, Records management in Exchange, etc.) and apart from the AdminAuditLogs folder it can query everything w/o error. (Eg. a `Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Root` works OK.)

Basically it's the same problem as 'Andy' had a few years ago (unanswered Q from social.msdn):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/56713fb3-f134-4d64-97d0-8516aa2fdedf/mailbox-audit-logging-access-via-ews?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know that folder isn't meant to be accessible via a client API like EWS. Eg because of the security implications that somebody else accessing the Mailbox could edit/delete the Log to hide their actions. All access should be done via the Exchange Management Shell cmdlets

Cheers
Glen